# Django Model.objects.all() queryset not distinct

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following Django 3.0 models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Bounty(models.Model):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey('Profile', related_name="created_bounties", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    original_completion = models.OneToOneField('ProfileTrophy', related_name="original_bounty",on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProfileTrophy(models.Model):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', related_name="bounty_completions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bounty = models.ForeignKey('Bounty', related_name="bounty_completions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

So the premise is that there are profiles, and bountys. Profiles can create bountys (stored as creators on the bounty). Profiles can complete a bounty, which is stored as a ProfileTrophy (trophy for completing the bounty) and they can complete bountys they created or bountys created by others (bounties can have many completions, but the original by the creator is stored in original_completion).

The problem I'm running into is that if I have two Profiles, Bob and Jim, and Bob creates a bounty called "Bounty 1" and completes it everything is fine. If Jim then completes "Bounty 1" everything works fine, except when I call either Bounty.objects.all() or Bob.created_bounties.all() I get `<QuerySet [<Bounty: Bounty 1>, <Bounty: Bounty 1>]>` and queryset[0]==queryset[1].

The database shows only one bounty, and everything looks as it should. If I look at the queryset SQL of Bounty.objects.all() I see

```
SELECT "core_bounty"."id" FROM "core_bounty" LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_profiletrophy" ON ("core_bounty"."id" = "core_profiletrophy"."bounty_id")
```

Which if I'm reading right the left outer join is the problem because it will match both ProfileTrophys and so return the bounty twice.

Any help on why this duplication is happening in the queryset and what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I should add that everything within the app works fine, I only noticed because the Bounty object shows up twice in the admin dashboard and it really bothered me.

Edit 2: Removing creator and original_completion from the Bounty model has no effect on the problem

Comment: You could just use distinct() in the query. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: That doesn't do anything, and distinct() shouldn't have to be used on an all() query. The second paragraph reads "By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it was related to something I left out, the Meta ordering was set to ["bounty_completions"] which was causing the ordering to need to call in the left join.